# gtkmm DrawingArea segmentation fault when reading from opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, gtk, gtkmm

I'm working on a simple OpenCV (v3.1) video capture application using gtkmm 3, and right now I'm trying to load a jpg image into a `DrawingArea` by way of taking a `Mat` object into a `Cairo::Context`.  The program is as follows below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Gtk::Window* mainWindow;
    Gtk::DrawingArea* videoBackground; 
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "com.twallis.OSD");

    Mat inImage, outImage;
    inImage = cv::imread("blackbackground.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
    cvtColor(inImage, outImage, CV_BGR2RGB);

    /*LOAD WIDGETS FROM BUILDER FILE*/
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder = Gtk::Builder::create();
    try{
        builder->add_from_file("OSD_drawing_background1.glade");    
    }
    catch(const Glib::FileError& ex){
        std::cerr << "fileError: " << ex.what() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    catch(const Glib::MarkupError& ex){
        std::cerr << "MarkupError: " << ex.what() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    catch(const Gtk::BuilderError& ex){
        std::cerr << "BuilderError " << ex.what() << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    builder->get_widget("mainWindow", mainWindow);
    builder->get_widget("videoBackground", videoBackground);

    Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> cairoContext = videoBackground-  >get_window()->create_cairo_context();
    Gdk::Cairo::set_source_pixbuf(cairoContext,    Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_data(outImage.data, Gdk::COLORSPACE_RGB, false, 8, outImage.cols, outImage.rows, outImage.step));

    mainWindow->add(*videoBackground);
    videoBackground->queue_draw();

    return app->run(*mainWindow);   }
```

When I compile the program using: `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -L/usr/local/lib -g OSDDrawingWindow.cpp -o drawing  -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 gtk+-3.0 --cflags --libs`

I receive no warnings, but running the program immediately results in a segfault.  Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!outImage.empty()) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.